# Differentiation under integral sign.

Tags: derivatives

There is a integral that has to be differentiated. In an article i studied that the derivative of the integral of a function is the integral of the derivative of that function with respect to some variable. The integral is:
$$\int_2^x [t-ty(t)]dt$$
please differentiate it with respect to $x$.

Comment: $x$ isn't under the integral sign. Try the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: @user251257 but x is one of the limits of integration.

Comment: that is the reason why I suggested the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F(x) = \int_2^x [t - ty(t)]\, dt$ and assume that $y$ is a continuous function.

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{F(x+h) - F(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h}\int_x^{x+h} [t - ty(t)] = x - x y(x) $$

Since for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that $|t - x| \leq \delta$ implies 
$$\big|t - t y(t) - (x - x y(x))\big|\leq \epsilon$$

There is no differentiation under the integral sign.

Edit: If $y$ is an arbitrary function, then in general you cannot differentiate it on $x$. Take $y(s) = f(s)\frac{1}{s}$ so $ F'(x) = x + \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h}\int_x^{x+h} f(s) $ wich might not exist, take for instance$$f(s) = \begin{cases}1 &s \geq x\\ -1 &s<x\end{cases}$$

Comment: How to deal with y(t)

Comment: Could you be more precise?

Comment: notice that $y$ need to be continuous or something like that...

Comment: There is y(t) under the integral. How is that integrated. The whole problem is related with it.

Comment: If $y$ is an arbitrary function, then in general you cannot differentiate it on $x$. Take $y(s) = f(s)\frac{1}{s}$ so $ F'(x) = x + \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h}\int_x^{x+h} f(s) $ wich might not exist --- take $$f(s) = \begin{cases}1 &s \geq x\\ -1 &s<x\end{cases}$$